# linux - add a line just before ending line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I want to write a linux script(`set_compiler.sh`) that will add a line just before the ending line.

The file `zazzercode.gwt.xml` is as below :

```
 1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  2 <!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.3.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.3.0/distro-s    ource/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
  3 <module rename-to="zazzercode">
  4         <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
  5         <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />
  6         <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP" />
  7         <inherits name="com.google.gwt.json.JSON"/>
  8 
  9         <inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder" />
 10         <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject" />
 11         <inherits name="com.gwtplatform.mvp.Mvp" />
 12         <inherits name="gwtquery.plugins.droppable.Droppable"/>
 13 
 14         <source path="client" />
 15         <source path="shared" />
 16 
 17         <define-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector" is-multi-valued="false"/>
 18         <set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector" value="com.zazzercode.client.mvp.ZazzercodeGInjector"/>
 19         <set-configuration-property name="UiBinder.useSafeHtmlTemplates" value="true" />
 20 
 21         <extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
 22         <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
 23         <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>
 24 
 25         <entry-point class="com.zazzercode.client.MainApp"/>
 26 
 27 </module>
```

When I fire `$ set_compiler` command, the script will have to add following line just before the ending line.

`<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />`

Something like the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6284624/432903) with a script.

```
sed -e '25a\ <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />' zazzercode.gwt.xml
```

Comment: WOuld it be an option, that you insert a placeholder like `___INSERT____AGENT____` into ` zazzercode.gwt.xml` and then use `sed` to replace it with the desired string?

Comment: Actually above file is a configuration file which will be compiled by GWT Compiler, so it doesn't accept `___INSERT____AGENT____` like keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following contents in the file `test`:

```
Here
are
some
lines
```

the following command gives the following output:

```
$ NL=$(wc -l test); sed ${NL%% *}'iMYNEWLINE' test
Here
are
some
MYNEWLINE
lines
```

Use `-i` with `sed` if your version supports it to edit the file in-place.

The real "magic" is the `sed` command of the form "`#itext`", where `#` is a line number, `i` denotes "insert" and `text` is the text to insert. Here it will expand to

```
sed '4iMYNEWLINE' test
```

I get the line count from `wc`. It gives output on the form:

```
$ wc -l test
4 test
```

but I only want the number, so I use shell brace expansion to clear everything matching the pattern `*`, that is "space and then anything". That part is just a quirk from the use of `wc`.

---

As I'm writing I see your edit that proposes using `sed` in more or less exactly this way, so I could have saved some writing, I guess :-) . In your case, the final command could be e.g.:

```
FN="zazzercode.gwt.xml"; NL=$(wc -l "$FN"); sed -i ${NL%% *}'i\ <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />' "$FN"
```

Note that I included `-i`: test the command without it before adding that switch.

Comment: Regarding in-place editing, see: [sed in-place flag that works both on Mac and Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694228/sed-in-place-flag-that-works-both-on-mac-and-linux)

Comment: Great. I will try to make it more dynamic. `#!/bin/sh
FN="zazzercode.gwt.xml"; NL=$(wc -l "$FN"); sed -i ${NL%% *}'i\ <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />' "$FN"
`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files are not *huge* and you can safely load them into memory, you could do this which avoids scanning the file twice (no `wc`):

```
perl -e 'open($fh,"$ARGV[0]"); @a=<$fh>; 
        $a[$#a-1]="<set-property name=\"user.agent\" value=\"safari\" />\n" .
            $a[$#a-1]; 
        print "@a\n";
' zazzercode.gwt.xml > new_file
```

Or, for a solution that uses coreutil tools only:

```
$ (head -n -2 zazzercode.gwt.xml; 
  echo "<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />"; 
  tail -n 1 zazzercode.gwt.xml) > new_file
```